# Conflict between defernumbers option and custom made environment

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, environments

I have a document (not-so-MWE below) for which I'd like to have a *type A documents* and *type B documents* bibliographies.
I use `biblatex` and the `\newrefcontext` command to achieve that.

This document also has a custom environment named `req`, in which text can be put.

The problem I'm facing is that, if any one of the *type A* or *type B* documents is cited *inside* the environment for the first time, the bibliography counter(s) does not work any more, returning [0] (or [TA-0] or [TB-0], as per the definition in the document) as a reference.

This does not happen if the documents are cited *outside* the `req` environment first (see line 130).

Apparently this behavior is not caused by the counters defined in the `req` environment (It was my fist thought, I tried some debugging).

Instead, it can be traced back to the `defernumbers=true` option of `biblatex`, which is required to achieve the proper numbering of the different `refcontext`.
By commenting it out, a numbering is achieved (even if it is not the correct one).

At the same time, I'm not able to recognize some valuable information from the log files.

How should I improve my own defined environment, so that the proper behavior of `biblatex` and `\newrefcontext` is restored?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,draft,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
    sorting       = none,
    defernumbers  = true,
    backend       = biber,
    % bibstyle    = ieee,
    % % citestyle = numeric,
    % isbn        = true,
    % doi         = false,
    % % sorting   = nty,
    % % sorting   = debug,
    % % url       = false,
    % bibencoding = utf8,
]{biblatex}

% required to define the 'req' environment:
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

%%% definition of the 'req' environment and its associated comments
\newcounter{reqCounter}
\counterwithin*{reqCounter}{section}

\newcommand{\theReqCounter}{%
    \padzeroes[3]{\decimal{reqCounter}}%
}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\reqlabel}[2]{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328051/177
\makeatother

\newenvironment{req}[9]
{ % begin code
    \refstepcounter{reqCounter}%
    \subsection{#2}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\scshape}lX}
            \toprule
            row 1 & {#1}-\theReqCounter \reqlabel{#8}{{#1}-\theReqCounter}  \\
            % id & {#1}-\theReqCounter \reqlabel{thisisthelabel}{thisisthereference} \\
            \midrule
            row 2 & #2 \\
            \midrule
            row 3 & #3 \\
            \midrule
            row 4 & #4 \\
            \midrule
            row 5 & #5 \\
            \midrule
            row 6 & #6 \\
            \midrule
            row 7 & #9 \\
            \midrule
            row 8 & #7 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
}
{ % end code
    % nothing to declare
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @TechReport{doc01,
        author      = {author, first},
        title       = {{project name doc 1}},
        institution = {company one},
        year        = {2021},
        type        = {type A},
        number      = {documet code 1},
        address     = {},
        keywords    = {tadoc},
    }

    @TechReport{doc02,
        author      = {author, first},
        title       = {{project name doc 2}},
        institution = {company one},
        year        = {2021},
        type        = {type A},
        number      = {documet code 2},
        address     = {},
        keywords    = {tadoc},
    }

    @TechReport{doc03,
        author      = {author, first},
        title       = {{project name doc 3}},
        institution = {company one},
        year        = {2021},
        type        = {type A},
        number      = {documet code 3},
        address     = {},
        keywords    = {tadoc},
    }

    @TechReport{doc04,
        author      = {author, second},
        title       = {{type B document title}},
        institution = {Company B},
        year        = {2021},
        type        = {Type B},
        number      = {n/a},
        address     = {},
        keywords    = {tbdoc},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=TA-]
\printbibliography[keyword=tadoc,title=Type A Documents]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=CD-]
\printbibliography[keyword=tbdoc,title=Type B Documents]



\chapter{first chapter}

%%% If the following cite commands are commented out, the references are printed as [0]
%%% Uncommenting the \cite commands the references behave normally as expected
% \cite{doc01}
% % \cite{doc02}
% % \cite{doc03}
% \cite{doc04}


\begin{req}{AA-BB}
{title 1}
{statement 1}
{\cite[page 4, Table 1,][]{doc01}}
{T}
{False}
{lorem ipsum}
{req:01} % no spaces between these brackets!
{}
\end{req}

\begin{req}{AA-CC}
{   title 2}
{   statement 2}
{ \cite[page 4, Table 1,][]{doc01}}
{ T}
{ False}
{ lorem ipsum}
{req:02} % no spaces between these brackets!
{}
\end{req}

\section{section title}

\begin{req}{BB-AA}
{title 3}
{statement 3}
{ \cite[page 29,][]{doc01}}
{ default}
{ False}
{ lorem ipsum}
{req:03} % no spaces between these brackets!
{n/a}
\end{req}

\begin{req}{BB-CC}
{title 5}
{statement 5}
{   \cite[page 29,][]{doc01}}
{ T}
{ False}
{ \cite{doc04}}
{req:05} % no spaces between these brackets!
{n/a}
lorem ipsum  \cite[Sec.~4, p.~13]{doc02} dolor sit amet \cite{doc04}
\end{req}

% \begin{req}{BB-DD}
% {title 6}
% {statement 6}
% {\cite[Sec.~xxx, p.~xxx][]{doc03}}
% % {  }
% { % verification method
%   R
% }
% { % verification status
%   False
% }
% { % validation
%   lorem ipsum
% }
% {req:06} % no spaces between these brackets!
% {n/a}
% \end{req}

\ref{req:01}
\ref{req:02}
\ref{req:03}
\ref{req:05}
\ref{req:06}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious: Can you please explain what exactly I need to do to reproduce the undesirable behaviour with the MWE as posted? I played around with the bits that were commented out, but could not reproduce any lasting issues with [0]s.

Comment: That said: Your custom environment builds upon `tabularx` and the newest `biblatex` version 3.13(a) fixed a nasty and quite elusive error with `tabularx` and `defernumbers` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184206/35864), so maybe that's what you are dealing with. What version of `biblatex` do you use?

Comment: hi @moewe! thanks for the suggestion! Even though I run a recent installation, my `biblatex` is still at Version 3.12.
I'll see what happens after updating the package

Comment: @moewe I've updated the code in the MWE to clarify what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `biblatex` to version >= 3.13 solves the issue.
See the question referenced as duplicate.